# htaccess redirect for _escaped_fragment_=

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to remove the `_escaped_fragment_=` that Google uses when it encounters a link with a `#` in it.  The Rewrite I'm trying to use is as follows:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*?)_escaped_fragment_=(.*)$ $1$2 [L]
```

This works when I try to use an online htaccess checker like http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/, but not when served through Apache.

Example, if I try to visit `site.com/_escaped_fragment_=pagename`, there is no redirection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you need `R` flag also. Try this rule:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*?)_escaped_fragment_=(.*)$ /$1$2 [L,NC,R]
```

Comment: Shouldn't `_escape_fragment_` be implemented as part of the query string portion of the URL? ie. `site.com?_escaped_fragment_=pagename`, not `site.com/_escaped_fragment_=pagename`? (In which case `RewriteRule` won't pick this up.)